# How to get html select to show selected value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, select

When I choose a value from the drop down list, I want to display the selected value in the drop down list. My code bellow is changing the content of the value on my page when i choose a value, but the drop down list always display the same value, instead of display the value that I have chosen.
I have tried so many different solutions, but I can not get It to work :(.
The option value is inside a Django for loop.

```
<div class="organizations">             
    <select id="select-organizations" name="forma" onchange="location = this.value;">
    {% for role in user.person.roles.all %}
    <option value="/org:{{ role.organization.number }}">
    {{ role.organization }}
    </option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Reason is simple... Page is being unloaded on `onchange` event and hence all the elements are reset..

Comment: Try `$('#select-organizations').val(window.location)`

Comment: @Rayon $('#select-organizations').val(window.location) is not working :(

Comment: So you change the option values and you want the select drop down to show the selected value? Or do you want the `window.location` variable to have the currently selected option value?

Comment: You might just define a `onchange` listener or any other trigger in javascript and just get the selected item doing `var e = document.getElementById("select-organizations"); var chosen = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; `

Comment: @VivekPradhan Hi! So you change the option values and you want the select drop down to show the selected value? YES :) , and your code is not working :(.